# como seleccionar el elemento hijo sobre el que se hace un mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, lista

Estoy intentando mostrar un elemento oculto dentro de una lista, debería mostrarse al pasar el ratón por encima del elemento padre pero no se como seleccionar ese elemento sin seleccionarlos todos, aqui dejo el ejemplo. Gracias.

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.sent > p', function (e) {
    let a = e.firstElementChild;
    $(a).fadeIn();
  });
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.sent > p', function (e) {
    let a = e.firstElementChild;
    $(a).fadeOut();
  });
```

```css
.sent{
   background: #44494fff;
   border-radius: 15px;
   width: -moz-max-content;
   height: -moz-max-content;
   min-width: 30px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding:0 15px;
   list-style: none;
   color: #fff;
}
.action{
   border: 1px solid #0000004d;
   background: #44494c;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="sent"><p>primer hijo <span class="action">boton</span></li>
 <li class="sent"><p>primer hijo <span class="action">boton</span></li>
 <li class="sent"><p>primer hijo <span class="action">boton</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en tu selector

Recuerda que *e* es solo el evento, para obtener el elemento tienes que usar `e.target`

En cuanto al selector, hay que cambiarle de `document` a `.sent` porque es el elemento que vamos a modificar

```js
$(".sent").on('mouseover', function (e) {
    $(e.target).find(".action").fadeIn();
});

$(".sent").on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    $(e.target).find(".action").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.sent{
   background: #44494fff;
   border-radius: 15px;
   width: -moz-max-content;
   height: -moz-max-content;
   min-width: 30px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding:0 15px;
   list-style: none;
   color: #fff;
}
.action{
   border: 1px solid #0000004d;
   background: #44494c;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="sent"><p>primer hijo <span class="action">boton</span></li>
 <li class="sent"><p>primer hijo <span class="action">boton</span></li>
 <li class="sent"><p>primer hijo <span class="action">boton</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ya que estás trabajando con jQuery, bien podrías usar `$(e.target).find("p > .action").fadeIn();`. Referencia: [jQuery.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/). Por lo demás, excelente respuesta.

Comment: @Triby Ya he aplicado el método, gracias por los comentarios

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Lo único que todavía me "hace ruido" es la creación de la variable, no se necesita, porque es suficiente con `$(e.target).find(".action").fadeIn();` o `$(e.target).find(".action").fadeOut();`.

Comment: Una última observación, `$(document).on('mouseover', '.sent', function (e) { ... })` es útil para _[delegar eventos](https://www.paradigmadigital.com/dev/entendiendo-delegacion-eventos-javascript/)_, generalmente usado cuando agregas elementos dinámicamente. De la otra forma, solo aplica para elementos existentes.

Comment: exacto es los elementos de la lista se crean dinamicamente con lo que se obtiene de la BD es por eso que lo use.

Comment: muchas gracias boy a probarlo ahora.